# How to remove/delete or skip a state in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to skip a state after logout in angular ui router SPA. But I am unable to acive this.

**dashboard -> login -> view details -> logout -> dashboard**

I am logging in dashboard and moving to details state and logging out there. On logout I am moving to dashboard. Now, if I press back button It is again going to view details page. How can I prevent to moving there. Please help me. How can I remove that `view details` state from history on logout. Of course the history not containing this page bcoz it is SPA. Button I observed them in browser back button long press

Comment: Keep a flag to check if the user is logged out. When you press back button, "OnStateChangeStart" event triggers, check for that flag value there and change the state accordingly.

Comment: Show us the code your have tried so far.

Comment: Easy solution is use `OnStateChangeStart`, best solution use angular permissions `permission, permission.ui`

Comment: @Rakeshchand thanks. i'll go through it. Can you please make an example as shown in my question. Need not to work but as an example